# Module '"*.svg"' has no exported member 'ReactComponent'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, svg, create-react-app

I created a new React app using CRA. Now, I want to create an index file that exports all of my icons. In order to do so, I stored all of my icons in my `src/icons` folder and created an index file that exports my icons as React elements.

The problem is, that I get the following error when trying to export `ReactComponent`:

```
Module '"*.svg"' has no exported member 'ReactComponent'. Did you mean to use 'import ReactComponent from "*.svg"' instead?
```

[image]

According to [CRA's docs](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-images-fonts-and-files/#adding-svgs), this should work without the need of declaring a new module.

I'm using the `react@^16.13.1` and `react-scripts@3.4.1` which supposed to support it.

The weird thing is, that when I run the code, I get neither compilation nor run-time errors. When I use `<ChevronRightIcon />` then the icon is displayed accordingly.

Answer (score 7):

Change declaration to

```
declare module '*.svg' {
    import React = require('react')
    export const ReactComponent: React.FC<React.SVGProps<SVGSVGElement>>
    const src: string
    export default src
}
```